# How to get a crash core dump in UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: crash

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS.

I need to get a **crash core dump** from an specific issue about PulseEffects (it doesn't run without reasons!).

But... The only one file I got, about that crash, is this:

[PulseEffects crash](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects/files/2544059/_usr_bin_pulseeffects.1000.txt)

Which is not useful to the person which is trying to help me (because he uses Arch Linux).

How can I get a crash core dump from this issue?

Comment: That IS a crash dump. There is a text description of what's in memory, what the system thinks about the process, and a base64 encoded core dump (see `man base64`). Also how is it AskUbuntu's problem if you get support from an Arch Linux person?

Comment: The person who is trying to help me is from the specific problematic app help forum (PulseEffects).